# HTAccess bug. GET doesn't seem to come through correctly

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm using the following htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^CuraXL/(.*)$  "CuraXL/index.php?pageRequest=$1"
RewriteRule ^CuraXL/(.*)/$  "CuraXL/index.php?pageRequest=$1"
```

When Doing the following in php:

```
<?php echo $_GET['pageRequest']; ?>
```

It outputs "index.php". Instead of what i request being "about-us".

Any idea what's up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `CuraXL/index.php` is also matched by `^CuraXL/(.*)$`. You need to exclude the destination you are rewriting to:

```
RewriteCond $1 !=index.php
RewriteRule ^CuraXL/(.*)/?$  CuraXL/index.php?pageRequest=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around the index.php bit in the .htaccess